# Are there concerns with doing a generalized additive model with a smoothing term of multiple variables?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

In R, usually one performs a generalized additive model like so:

```
library(mgcv)
x <- gam(depvar ~ s(indvar1) + s(indvar2) + parametricvar)
```

Say I want to explore the non-parametric interaction of `indvar1` and `indvar2`.

Is the following kosher?

```
x <- gam(depvar ~ s(indvar,indvar2) + parametricvar)
```

Comment: @MrFlick, I think he means "Kosher" as if this the right syntax. He seems to be familiar with the statistical side of it

Answer (score 2):

In order to determine whether s() will gracefully accept two terms, we need to know the data structure. If one of them, say var2, is categorical you will probably need to use `s(var1, by=var2)`. You could also look at other spline representations such as `te(.)` that are designed to accept multiple variables:

```
require(mgcv)
?d
?te
```

I cracked open my copy of Simon Wood's text and these issues are discussed in pages 225 to 240. I think anyone using mgcv should probably buy that text.